# Is there a way to set DEBUG for all tags in Android's ADB?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, adb

I know I can set DEBUG in Android's ADB by typing:

adb shell setprop log.tag.MyTag DEBUG

What I'm wondering is if there is a way to set debug for all my classes that do logging instead of having to type the above multiple times:

adb shell setprop log.tag.MyTag1 DEBUG
adb shell setprop log.tag.MyTag2 DEBUG
adb shell setprop log.tag.MyTag3 DEBUG
adb shell setprop log.tag.MyTag4 DEBUG

Something like:

adb shell setprop log.tag.* DEBUG

I'm using Eclipse for developing, but I'm currently setting the DEBUG through the command line adb.

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't see the purpose to use a per class tagging in debug.

Instead you should use per Application tagging.

Comment: Well, not per class exactly but multiple tags for different parts of the application (so I could not see debugging for parts that I'm not interested in).

Comment: Though maybe there is another way to do that with the filters?

Comment: You only see what's running and produces Debug outputs. Probably not all other parts are running once on your device, so a application wide tag would work ok. I don't know any other method.